# Get current date from user's computer on web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webforms

How can I get the user's current date running web site? [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return server's rather user. I guess I'll get some luck by evaluating javascript using C#, I want to know if there's a more elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that javascript executes on client side, so you will retrieve date of computer user. While on the application running on server side you will get date of server.

It depends what do you need to do, and where you will use the date.

If the server needs to know the date of user, then you will have to send it in your request.

Answer (score 1):

Open solution is to use the request ip address to get Geolocation, then derives the timezone and local time from server side. This might not be very reliable.
Another option is to always have the local time sent with each request.